# How can i get updated land longitude every 15 minute?

Tags: android

I am new to android . I will get latitude and longitude of android device using below code but I want updated latitude and longitude every 15 minute. How can i get this?
Please help me .

Thanks in advance.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
    longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView04);

    // Get the location manager
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
    // default
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    // Initialize the location fields
    if (location != null) {
        System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
        int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
        int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
        latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
        longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
    } else {
        latituteField.setText("Provider not available");
        longitudeField.setText("Provider not available");
    }
}

/* Request updates at startup */
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
}

/* Remove the locationlistener updates when Activity is paused */
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
    int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
    latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
    longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Disenabled provider " + provider,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i send latitude longitude of android device every 15minute to php web service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440470/how-can-i-send-latitude-longitude-of-android-device-every-15minute-to-php-web-ser/7440507#7440507).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok,

```
!. Start a service or thread from  your activity.

2. put a timer for every 15 minutes.

3. at every 15 minutes just call the onLocationChanged() for location update and 
   save it then pass the value to your activity and use it.
```

Now I think this time you understand it.

EDIT: also for location update just check the previous question as I mentioned in comment above.

Thanks. :-)