# How can I send latitude longitude of android device every 3 minutes in back end to php web service

Tags: java, android

based on app id send [latitude and longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440470/how-can-i-send-latitude-longitude-of-android-device-every-15minute-to-php-web-server) and time send to server and use of alram manager

Comment: U can set time interval to 3 minutes using location manager and request location updates. Now inside onLocationChanged() u can call php  webservice and send the updated lat,lng.

Comment: What did you try so far? Whats the problem you are stuck with?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i send latitude longitude of android device every 15minute to php web service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440470/how-can-i-send-latitude-longitude-of-android-device-every-15minute-to-php-web-se)

Comment: You need to use alrmmanager to trigger every 3 minutes

Comment: okay pls send the code

Comment: Okay ,thaks for reply

Answer (score 3):

1. Request Location updates using LocationManager.

   ```
   NetworkListener listener = new NetworkListener()

   locationManager.requestLocationUpdates (LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 30000, 0, listener);
   ```
2. Inside Listener onLocationChanged u can write code to send lat, lng to php webservice.

   ```
   class NetworkListener implements LocationListener{

       public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             double latitude = location.getLatitude();
             double longitude = location.getLongitude();
             // write code to send lat, lng to php webservice.
       }

       public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       } 

       public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       }
       public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       }

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use timer task that will trigger after each 3 minutes. Please refer below code for that

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
         timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {       
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {       
                     /// send lat and long here to your server

                    }
                });
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 300000)
```

Answer (score 0):

User [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

First Please check the [Scheduling Repeating Alarms](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) on android developer site.

and check the following answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7687485/957654) it explains how to run every 5 seconds.

finally check the following [tutorial](http://karanbalkar.com/2013/07/tutorial-41-using-alarmmanager-and-broadcastreceiver-in-android/), it explains how to run a service(in your case to call the backend).

Hope that Helps.